# How could Subathirai and Balarama are mentioned in Satya yuga (Krita yuga) in Brahma purana while they belong in Dwapara yuga?

Tags: brahma-purana

In one of the stories from Brahma purana about Indradhyumna, it is mentioned that in Satya yuga, a king built a temple where Vishwakarma in disguise built three statues: Balarama, Krishna and Subathirai (Krishna's sister). All these three characters appear only in Dwapara yuga, in that case how come they could be mentioned in Satya yuga?

Comment: The avatars of Lord Krishna, Lord Balarama & their sister Subhadra are of Dwapar Yuga only. If it is mentioned as Satya yuga, then it might be due to an error.

Comment: I found it in a tamil book about brahma purana. I too thought that it could be an error then later I found a blog with the same story : [link]http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahma-purana/d/doc57564.html

Comment: Balarama, Krishna and Subhadra are eternal deities. They exist eternally, not only in Satya yuga.